# How to add 100MB of swap space as a logical volume in CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos

I need to add 100MB of swap space to my machine. I was trying to use a logical volume.

```
# lvcreate –name lv_swap2 –size 100M vg
# mkswap /dev/vg/lv_swap2
# swapon /dev/vg/lv_swap2
# vi /etc/fstab
/dev/vg/lv_swap2 swap defaults 0 0
```

It doesn't work... Need help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote everything right but missed something here: swap swap defaults

```
# lvcreate –name lv_swap2 –size 100M vg
# mkswap /dev/vg/lv_swap2
# swapon /dev/vg/lv_swap2
# vi /etc/fstab
/dev/vg/lv_swap2 *swap* swap defaults 0 0
```

Now it should work.